# Not mapping controlles on Nestjs project

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nestjs-config

not mapping controllers on my terminal

its showing
[10:28:18 am] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[10:28:24 am] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

tried almost everything not getting any results,
everything  imported properly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.